# Is there a way of solving similar ODEs?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

**Setup:** We have (all) solutions $y_k(x)$ of an inhomogeneous, (possibly non-linear) first-order ODE

$P(x)(y)=0$

where the coefficients of $P(x)(y)$ are monomials in $x$.

**Question:** *Are we now able to find solutions of* $P(x+1)(y)=0$?

The Problem where this question occured is the non-linear ODE

$(x+1)^5(y')^2+3(x+1)^4y'y+\frac94(x+1)^3y^2+\frac{\pi^2}4*(1-(x+1)^3)=0$

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your question, but If you note $E_0$ your original differential equation (given in example, $x^5(y^{\prime})^2+...$; you say you know all the solutions) and $E_1$ the new equation $(x+1)^5 (y^{\prime})^2+...$, have you noticed that if $z(x)$ is solution of $E_1$, then $y(x)=z(x-1)$ is solution of the original equation ?

Comment: This was probably not one of my brightest moments after hours of sorting terms by order..

Thank you